# Quick way to switch between pasword-protected screen and no protection?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lock-screens, 4.3-jelly-bean

When I have my android phone with me, I don't want it to be password or pin protected.

When I don't have my android phone with me, I want it to be password or pin protected.

Switching between the two cases requires everytime going into Settings -> Lock Screen, to enter new password or pin. Is there a quicker way to switch? Thanks.

My Android phones are 4.4.2 and 4.3 respectively.

Comment: Okay...just please tell us, how will the phone know where are you, and are you the owner? 
You could use knock code or pattern, since they are fast and easy to enter.

Comment: I am the owner. What are knock code or pattern?

Comment: Knock code and Pattern are two additional types of screen lock which you can adjust in your settings.
Settings>Display>Lock screen>Select screen lock
OR
Settings > Screen security

Answer (score 1):

That does not exist. You could change the lock screen type in Settings?
That what you are searching for, is that the phone "knows" the owner. But the cell phone is not pure artificial intelligence. Or on the other way you need a small piece of hardware that is connected with Bluetooth with your phone. That means that little piece of hardware needs to be all the time with you. And again that might be available but I'm unfamiliar with it. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
Go to Settings ➡ Personal ➡ Lock Screen and Security ➡ Secure Lock Settings ➡ Smart Lock.
Here you will find these four options:

[image: Smart Lock]

On-body detection seems to be exactly what you're asking about, and you may as also find trusted places get helpful, for example, keeping your phone unlocked while you're at home or at work.